# Program crashes when starting process.Start() at windows start up

Tags: c#, startup, process.start

I have 2 exe, A.exe and B.exe.    A.exe is added to the registry's run key so that it starts with windows start up.
Inside of A's main, there is this code:

```
Process pr = new Process(); 
pr.StartInfo.FileName = "B.exe"; 
pr.StartInfo.Arguments = SomeArgs; 
pr.Start();
```

Both A and B is in the same directory. If I launch A manually by double clicking it, it works fine, B starts up fine. But, when I tried to restart windows to check if it works fine at windows start up, every time A.exe crashed and hence B.exe was never launched. I thought it was some other problem in A, maybe system was slow to load some dependencies but no, when I removed the above part of code, everything works fine on windows start up, A dont crash but B is not launched. So what could be the problem or how to solve this?

Edit: 
used a try catch, and this came up, I have no idea why this came up though:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file
>   specified at
>   System.Diagonstics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessSt‌​artInfo
>   startInfo) at System.Diagonostics.Process.Start() at
>   System.Diagonostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName, String arguments) at
>   ....

I even tried with full file path still same error. But, manually launching it causes no error and works perfectly fine. Its just that this windows start up is messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

try that one

```
Process pr = new Process(); 
pr.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath+"/B.exe"; 
pr.StartInfo.Arguments = SomeArgs; 
pr.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be running into a Security error. Process requires certain permissions to work. See the Security section notes here:

[Process Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Figure out a way to log the issue and see if this is the problem you are running into.

Comment: used a try catch, and this came up, I have no idea why this came up though: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified at System.Diagonstics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagonostics.Process.Start() at System.Diagonostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName, String arguments) at ....

Comment: I even tried with full file path still same error. But, manually launching it causes no error and works perfectly fine.

Comment: This essentially means the path to the executable is wrong. I know you mentioned you tried the full path. Does your path contain spaces?

Comment: Also, are you placing your files in system directories? (e.g. C:\Windows\)

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify WorkingDirectory:

```
Process pr = new Process(); 
pr.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\path\to";
pr.StartInfo.FileName = "B.exe"; 
pr.StartInfo.Arguments = SomeArgs; 
pr.Start();
```